# .htaccess make friendly url's

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I have website www.example.com/index.php?q=registration I would like to redirect it into www.example.com/registration

This code doesn't seems to work, but I don't know why.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ /$1[L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because your rewrite rule is expecting a .html. Point your browser to

```
www.example.com/registration.html
```

should work with your htaccess;  Another rule you can put in there is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's a good idea to add the QSA flag to both your rules as well to make sure that any other query string parameters are appended.

In the end your .htaccess should be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|gif|php)$  - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^a-z0-9_]+)*$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: oh, my false, but if I write www.example.com/registration it shows 404 error, it works only with registration.html

Comment: write www.example.com/registration/

Comment: updated the answer to help you out a bit more... Read  up on regular expressions

Comment: still without success, but Ajeesh's solution works. Anyway thanks for help.